# Подсчет частоты вхождения пар значений в строках DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Всем привет!

Интересует как правильно и красиво написать python code.
Возможно ли для решения ниже приведенной задачи использовать только функции pandas или другие библиотеки и не использовать циклы for/while? 
Как написать с помощью for я знаю, но решение мне кажется громозким.

Задача - для всех возможных комбинаций букв AB, AC, ..., XY, XZ, YZ подсчитать в скольких строках встречалась каждая комбинация букв. Буквы в строках предварительно надо отсортировать по возрастанию и по условию задачи буквы в строке не могут повторяться.
Из результата нужно выбрать 10 наиболее часто встречаемых пар букв.

Входные данные

```
A, B, J, K
B, E, P, A
R, Z, A, B
K, L, M, A
X, A, J, K
```

Результата запроса

```
A,B,3
A,J,2
A,K,3
B,J,1
B,K,1
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нам понадобятся все комбинации пар столбцов:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

cc = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
```

получилось:

```
In [39]: cc
Out[39]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

теперь можно найти все встречающиеся пары букв:

```
t = np.concatenate([np.sort(df.loc[:, c], axis=1).sum(1) for c in cc])
```

получилось:

```
In [43]: t
Out[43]:
array(['AB', 'BE', 'RZ', 'KL', 'AX', 'AJ', 'BP', 'AR', 'KM', 'JX', 'AK', 'AB', 'BR', 'AK', 'KX', 'BJ', 'EP', 'AZ', 'LM', 'AJ', 'BK', 'AE', 'BZ', 'AL', 'AK', 'JK', 'AP', 'AB', 'AM', 'JK'],
      dtype=object)
```

теперь можно воспользоваться `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

res = Counter(t).most_common(10)
```

результат:

```
In [46]: res
Out[46]:
[('AB', 3),
 ('AK', 3),
 ('AJ', 2),
 ('JK', 2),
 ('BE', 1),
 ('RZ', 1),
 ('KL', 1),
 ('AX', 1),
 ('BP', 1),
 ('AR', 1)]
```

Также можно создать Series из `t` и воспользоваться стандартными методами Pandas вместо испольования `collections.Counter`:

```
s = pd.Series(t)
res = s.groupby(s).size().nlargest(10)
```

результат:

```
In [49]: res
Out[49]:
AB    3
AK    3
AJ    2
JK    2
AE    1
AL    1
AM    1
AP    1
AR    1
AX    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
   0  1  2  3
0  A  B  J  K
1  B  E  P  A
2  R  Z  A  B
3  K  L  M  A
4  X  A  J  K
```